# read txt file start from the botton

Tags: python, selenium, file, webdriver, txt

My txt file is beeing read incorectly, when I send keys with my code it's only reading the last line of my txt file, instead of reading 1st line and then the next one

```
f = open('list.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8').readlines()
    for word in f:
        if word == "\n":
            continue
        elif not 0 < len(word) < 280:
            continue
        print(word)
    
     driver.find_element_by_xpath(message_paste).send_keys(word)
        print(word)
```

Result : the code send the very last line of my txt file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't replicate this. Check indentation. The following snippet works for me.

```
f = open('list.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8').readlines()
for word in f:
    if word == "\n":
        continue
    elif not 0 < len(word) < 280:
        continue
    print(word)
```